# Searching at DuckDuckGo on a phrase wrapped in inverted commas

Tags: duckduckgo

At DuckDuckGo, inverted commas are advised when you need to search on an exact phrase. But if the engine can find few or no pages that contain the phrase, it tries to "help" you by bringing to your attention sites that may be "close" to what you are looking for.

Can I assume that if I search for an exact phrase using the correct syntax of inverted commas and **the first linked result does not contain that exact phrase**, then **the engine found NO pages that contain it**?

I realise the answer is probably "yes", but I am seeking confirmation.

Or perhaps there is a special syntax that will yield a message saying "No pages found" if you are absolutely sure you want to know only about pages that contain an exact phrase?

Comment: "At DuckDuckGo, inverted commas are advised when you need to search on an exact phrase." Can you please point to an official source? I need to comprove this is not an original hypotesis of yours.